# org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: spring

I am getting this error, which is given below"

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException) (Caused by org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException))
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:543)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractApplicationContext.java:161)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:90)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractRefreshableConfigApplicationContext.java:59)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.<init>(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.student.test.aop.AOPmain.main(AOPmain.java:11)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: java.lang.NullPointerException (Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:529)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getLogConstructor(LogFactoryImpl.java:374)
    ... 11 more
```

I have already included the jar's "com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar" and "com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15.jar", but unable to find out why this error is coming.

Please help me.... to solve out this problem..

**here is my spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<bean name="triangle" class="com.student.test.aop.model.Triangle">
    <property name="name" value="Triangle name"/>
</bean>

<bean name="circle" class="com.student.test.aop.model.Circle">
    <property name="name" value="Circle name"/>
</bean>

<bean name="shapeService" class="com.student.test.aop.service.ShapeService" autowire="byName"/>

<bean name="loggingAspect" class="com.student.test.aop.aspect.LoggingAspect"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: please show spring version that you use

Comment: please someone help me solve this error

Comment: please show your pom.xml (in case of maven), or supply versions of libraries you use. Specially, spring versions.

Comment: Now i am getting another error which is given in this link.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/C1kP6zgS

Comment: The version of spring jar file i am using are com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15.jar, commons-logging-1.1.3.jar

Comment: Please look, if commons-logging.jar is available in runtime classpath. It is also possible not to be included in your package (jar or war).